# Exception: A column named 'Latitude' already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To listbox2.items.Count - 1
            If ListBox2.text = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
                dt.Columns.Add("X Coordinate")
                dt.Columns.Add("Y Coordinate")
            ElseIf ListBox2.text = "Latitude, Longitude" Then
                dt.Columns.Add("Latitude")
                dt.Columns.Add("Longitude")
            End If
        Next
        Dim mr As DataRow
        mr = dt.NewRow
        mr("X Coordinate") = "sdsf"
        mr("Y Coordinate") = "sdfsdf"
        mr("Latitude") = "AsDASDASD"
        mr("Longitude") = "AsDASDASD"
        dt.Rows.Add(mr)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Stuck on this error for a few hours now. Looked up other stack overflow question posts but none answered why i was getting this issue.

Comment: You are adding the column twice. add it before the loop just once

Comment: not sure where to add it just once. can you describe where and what please.

Comment: how many value: "Latitude, Longitude" on the list

Comment: You are adding datatable columns for each item in ListBox2. Maybe you could just use column names like `X - Long` and `Y - Lat`?

Comment: what i am trying to do is add all the columns to the grid view with the string texts for each row item. however, it keeps saying cant find the column name now. I want to add both columns but only only either lat, lon is getting added or x or y is getting added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must tes by item of list ListBox2.Items(i).ToString() and you can also test if th columns are alredy exists in datatable :

```
  If ListBox2.Items(i).ToString() = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
                If (Not columns.Contains("X Coordinate")) Then dt.Columns.Add("X Coordinate")
                If (Not columns.Contains("Y Coordinate")) Then dt.Columns.Add("Y Coordinate")
            ElseIf ListBox2.text = "Latitude, Longitude" Then
               If (Not columns.Contains("Latitude")) Then dt.Columns.Add("Latitude")
                If (Not columns.Contains("Longitude")) Then  dt.Columns.Add("Longitude")
            End If
```

Comment: please give me an upvote on the question as this answer helped. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the loop. Always check the same text of the ListBox. I understand that you want to compare the text of each element of the ListBox.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 0 To listbox2.items.Count - 1
            If ListBox2.Items(i).ToString() = "X,Y Coordinate" Then
                dt.Columns.Add("X Coordinate")
                dt.Columns.Add("Y Coordinate")
            ElseIf ListBox2.Items(i).ToString() = "Latitude, Longitude" Then
                dt.Columns.Add("Latitude")
                dt.Columns.Add("Longitude")
            End If
        Next
        Dim mr As DataRow
        mr = dt.NewRow
        mr("X Coordinate") = "sdsf"
        mr("Y Coordinate") = "sdfsdf"
        mr("Latitude") = "AsDASDASD"
        mr("Longitude") = "AsDASDASD"
        dt.Rows.Add(mr)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```